# Is it possible to pass webpack entry items config options without using a query string?

Tags: javascript, configuration, webpack, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

So I have the following webpack server config for hot reloading:

```
const compiler = webpack(dev);
const settings = middleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: dev.output.publicPath,
    path: `/__webpack_hmr`,
    quiet: true
});
```

And an `entry` that looks like this:

```
entry: [
    './src/app.js',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true'
],
```

Now originally I had this:

```
const compiler = webpack(dev);
const settings = middleware(compiler, {
    publicPath: dev.output.publicPath,
    path: `/__webpack_hmr`,
    quiet: true,
    reload: true
});
```

And

```
 entry: [
    './src/app.js',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client'
 ],
```

But after creating an issue on the [webpack-hot-middleware](https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware) I got this [comment](https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/180#issuecomment-283012906) back from the developer explaining that the query string format applies the config to the client where as the other format applies it to the server.

My question is, is there a way to apply the `reload=true` not using a query string, I find this format really hard to follow and difficult to keep track of.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through [their documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#entry) there's no explicit support. That being said, looking through [their code](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/DynamicEntryPlugin.js#L39) it looks like it's possible to pass a function which returns an array of the format you're currently passing in, however in testing I wasn't able to produce this. Another way would just be define and run your helper function. You could use a helper like this:

```
function buildEntries(entries) {
  return entries.map(function(entry) {
    if (typeof entry === 'object') {
      var options = '?';
      if (entry.options) {
        for (var option in entry.options) {
          if (entry.options.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            options += option + '=' + entry.options[option];
          }
        }
      }
      return entry.base + options.slice(0, -1);
    }
    // In all other cases
    return entry;
}
```

And then use it like in the full example below:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

function buildEntries(entries) {
  return entries.map(function(entry) {
    if (typeof entry === 'object') {
      var options = '?';
      if (entry.options) {
        for (var option in entry.options) {
          if (entry.options.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            options += option + '=' + entry.options[option];
          }
        }
      }
      return entry.base + options.slice(0, -1);
    }
    // In all other cases
    return entry;
}

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: buildEntries([
    {
      base: 'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      options: {
        path: '/__webpack_hmr',
        timeout: 20000
      }
    },
    './client.js'
  ]),
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: '#source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
};
```